# Setting up OpenCV(2.4.13) in Cuda(8.0) Project Visual studio 2013

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cuda

hi i'm trying to set up OpenCV for Cuda Project in visual studio 2013 . I even tried to follow this guide https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/ . but i couldn't setup . i have already worked on nsight eclipse before in ubuntu and it was rather very easy to setup in ubuntu. I just had to include certain libraries,etc . I have also tried the following guide for visual studio 2013 cuda project: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html
can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: thanks @Noah Christopher for correction.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My problem is solved finally i was able to set up cuda project for opencv in visual studio 2013 . I followed the guide as shown in the 2nd link . What i did wrong was i had x64 windows 10 os and i was trying to compilte with Win32 Configuration.